# Is it possible to pack multiple images into a single TFRecord example?

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm in a situation where the input into my ML model is a variable number of images per example (but only 1 label for each set), and so I would like to be able to pack multiple images into a single TFRecord example. However, every example i come across online is single image, single label, which is understandable because that's the most common use-case. I also wonder about decoding...it appears that tf.image.decode_png only does one image at a time, but perhaps I can convert all the images to tf.string and use tf.decode_raw, then resize to get all the images?

Thanks

Comment: Here is [an example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) where they write variable no of bounding boxes to a tfrecord. 
In your case, your could simply write out the list of filenames to your tfrecord and when you are parsing it, get each filename and using the tf.image.decode methods available get all your images with the associated label